# " iframe.contentDocument" Not Working in IE8 and FF(3.5 and below) any other steps to solve this?

Tags: javascript, iframe, uploader

I used this "iframe.contentDocument" in js file-uploader , But it not working in IE8 ,Firefox(3.5 and below versions.
How can i solve this by using other DOM's for working with iframe ?

Thanks to all

Comment: I believe there are differences between how IE, FF, etc., handles iframe.contentDocument. You could try a jQuery approach. Check out http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=29359

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
var doc;
var iframeObject = document.getElementById('iframeID'); // MUST have an ID
if (iframeObject.contentDocument) { // DOM
  doc = iframeObject.contentDocument;
} 
else if (iframeObject.contentWindow) { // IE win
  doc = iframeObject.contentWindow.document;
}
if (doc) {
  var something = doc.getElementById('someId');
}
else {
  alert('Wonder what browser this is...'+navigator.userAgent);
}
```