# Question about Javascript getElementsByTagName method

Tags: javascript

I set the onclick event handler of one button in one of my iframes to add content to the
table of another iframe of the same window,I use

```
var w = parent.frames[1].getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

this function should return a HTMLcollection object which is an Array-like object,but it seems that firefox and chrome can not parse my code because it can not execute

```
alert("here") ;
```

I placed after the getelement instruction,does anyone have a idea what is wrong,I am new to Web programming...

Comment: It is plural. getElementsByTagName

Comment: sorry,I mistyped it here,but I did not mistype it in my code,so there is still something wrong...I think it is related to the frame

Answer (score 6):

The function is `getElementsByTagName("tag");` with a 's'.

Comment: sorry,I mistyped it here,but I did not mistype it in my code,so there is still something wrong...I think it is related to the frame

Answer (score 0):

You need a document object

[" iframe.contentDocument" Not Working in IE8 and FF(3.5 and below) any other steps to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310946/iframe-contentdocument-not-working-in-ie8-and-ff3-5-and-below-any-other-step)

```
var doc;
var iframeObject = parent.document.getElementById('iframeID'); // MUST have an ID
if (iframeObject.contentDocument) { // DOM
  doc = iframeObject.contentDocument;
} 
else if (iframeObject.contentWindow) { // IE win
  doc = iframeObject.contentWindow.document;
}
if (doc) {
  var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr");
}
else {
  alert('Wonder what browser this is...'+navigator.userAgent);
}
```

assuming the same domain