# Site not rendering in IE 8 or 9 but ok in 10, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer-8, render

Our website is showing fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE10 but in IE9 the product name dissapears and in IE8 the page does not show at all. This is affecting our visitors

A page example is http://www.nutricentre.com/p-16973-anti-stretch-mark-cream.aspx

Any ideas what is causing it? I have tried everything and currently have added

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
```

in the header tag

Comment: Rather than asking us to unpick your site, please provide a simplified example that illustrates your problem. This is a browser compatibility problem, but finding it in all your code could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

On debugging your site in IE, Your problem is looking to be in Js file where you have used `contentwindow` property of an iframe obect!

(eg. in core081.js you have used `atf.contentWindow.postMessage(s,"*")`).

as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310946/iframe-contentdocument-not-working-in-ie8-and-ff3-5-and-below-any-other-ste) suggest, contentwindow is not supported directly in IE8. that should be the problem you are facing in case of IE8.

To resolve you can try this way, eg.:

```
var doc;
var iframeObject = document.getElementById('iframeID'); 
if (iframeObject.contentDocument) { // DOM
  doc = iframeObject.contentDocument;
} 
else if (iframeObject.contentWindow) { // IE win
  doc = iframeObject.contentWindow.document;
}
```

and use your `doc` object directly at place of `iframeObject.contentWindow`.